# How to redirect just the sub dir and not the content?

Tags: http-redirect

I have the following setup:

```
http://example.com/foo/cake1.php
http://example.com/foo/cake2.php
http://example.com/foo/cake3.php
```

And when I user visits:

```
http://example.com/foo
```

I want to send them to:

```
http://example.com
```

And preserve

```
http://example.com/foo/cake[1-3].php
```

etc.

I've tried:

```
Redirect /foo /
```

But that redirects everything under foo. I only want to redirect foo to the root. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/$ /
```